# Задан массив А из N чисел

Tags: c++, массивы

Задан массив А из N чисел. В массиве А рядом могут стоять одинаковые числа. Образовать массив В, подсчитав количество повторяющихся чисел в массиве А, стоящих рядом. Например, массив А был (2,0,0,1,4,4,3,5,5,5), тогда массив В будет (1,2,1,2,1,3).

Мой код не работает нужным образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{    
        int arr[10];
        int mas[10];
        
        
        cout <<"Enter massive numbers\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            cout << "[" << i + 1 << "]" << ": ";
            cin >> arr[i];
        }

        // И выводим заполненный массив.
        cout << "\nYour massive :  ";

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
        {
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
        }
         
        cout << "\nYour massive :  ";
        int last=arr[0];
        int index=0;
        for (int i=1;i<10;++i)
        {
            
            if (arr[i]==last) 
                {mas[index]++;}
            else {index++;
            mas[index]=1;last=arr[i];}
            cout << mas[index] << " ";
        }
    
            
        
        cout << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: я пытаюсь, но у меня ни как  не получается

Comment: Блин, ну это элементарнейшая задача. Натурально скоро будут спрашивать, как сложить `2+2` (

Comment: ну у меня не получается, я новичок. Что тут такого. Это мой вопрос, не можешь ответить не отвечай

Comment: Так, ну код с виду нормальный, осталось вывести получившийся массив. Вопрос в чём?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
  {
            cout << mas[index] << " ";
  }

Comment: вывод не правильный, числа так не выводятся как в примере

Comment: help plz. Я не знаю как еще пробовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый элемент у вас никак не учитывается, это можно исправить, например, задав единицу ещё перед циклом подсчёта:

```
int last=arr[0];
int index=0;
mas[0] = 1; // учитываем первый элемент
```

Ну и вывод в конце нужно добавить, учитывая при этом получившееся число элементов нового массива, которое у вас находится в `index`:

```
cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i <= index; ++i) 
{
    cout << mas[i] << " "; 
}
```

Тогда вроде всё правильно работает.

Comment: спасибо большое вроде получилось.

Comment: @ДаниилМартынович Тогда примите ответ как правильный (там должна быть галочка такая). На будущее прилагайте сразу код к вопросу, без кода тут считается, что вы вообще не пытались ничего делать, такое тут не приветствуется :)